# [Vue warn]: Property "$primevue" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

**Case and problem**

I´m working on a private project with `Vue.js` and have the following error, which occurs when I´m trying to use the `FileUpload` component of `PrimeVue`:

```
[Vue warn]: Property "$primevue" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
```

Trying to use `FileUpload` in my component:

```html
<template>
  <FileUpload name="demo[]" url="" @upload="onUpload" :multiple="true" :maxFileSize="1000000">
    <template #empty>
      <p>Drag and drop files to here to upload.</p>
    </template>
  </FileUpload>
</template>
```

The error only occurs, when I try to use `FileUpload`, if I remove it, the component works. `FileUpload` and `PrimeVue` are imported like they should, in the `main.js`:

```js
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";
import PrimeIcons from "primevue/config";
import App from "./App";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(
    router,
    PrimeVue,
    PrimeIcons,
    store
)

import 'primevue/resources/primevue.min.css'
import 'primeflex/primeflex.css'
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css'
import 'primevue/resources/themes/bootstrap4-dark-purple/theme.css'

import Card from "primevue/card";
import Menubar from "primevue/menubar";
import FileUpload from "primevue/fileupload";

app.component('Card', Card)
app.component('Menubar', Menubar)
app.component('FileUpload', FileUpload)

app.mount('#app')
```

**What I tried so far**

I searched this issue, but the only exact match for this error is an old closed issue on GitHub regarding the `Calendar` component: [Issue #808](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues/808). The error in this issue was caused because of the breaking change with the new `PrimeVue API`. This should not be my case, because it was introduced with V3.1 and I´m using V3.7.

In case the version is the problem I tested different versions of `PrimeVue`, like 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 but the error still shows. Thats why the actual dependencie is still the latest:

```
"primevue": "^3.7.0"
```

Maybe there is an already existing solution on SO or Google, but either my english is to bad to understand or I´m still to fresh at `Vue.js` to comprehend the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your usage of [`app.use()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#use) is incorrect:

```js
app.use(
    router,
    PrimeVue,
    PrimeIcons,
    store
)
```

`app.use()` takes only two arguments:

- *first argument:* the Vue plugin
- *second argument:* the plugin options

Also, `PrimeIcons` is not a plugin, so that should not be passed to `app.use()`.

### Solution

Pass each plugin individually to `app.use()`:

```js
app.use(router)
   .use(PrimeVue)
   //.use(PrimeIcons)   // not a plugin
   .use(store)
```

Comment: I have a follow up question on this: how was it possible that `Card` and `MenuBar` worked without any error?

Comment: `PrimeVue`'s [plugin installation](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/714d339/src/components/config/PrimeVue.js#L94) only sets up a Vue global and provides configuration for localization, z-index, ripple effect, filter matching, and input styles. That's completely independent of its component registration. The [`Card`](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/367d4a5/src/components/card/Card.vue) component is self contained, so you could actually use it without installing the `PrimeVue` plugin. Same with `MenuBar`.